# PLSQL Procedure return true if first condition is matching

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have the below code snippet in a procedure, would like to optimize and reviewed to improve code efficiency and standards.

The query selects three departments from first table and assigns to three local variables, then for loop is opened to check the department is matching and close the loop.
Ideally I would like to stop processing if the first if condition is true, if not then second and if not third condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `EXIT WHEN` ... or `GOTO` as follows:

```
....
....
<<my_loop>>
FOR CUR_REC IN ( SELECT DEPT
                   FROM (
                     SELECT DISTINCT DEPT
                       FROM MYTABLES
                 ) -- ACTUAL CODE IS QUITE COMPLEX QUERY
LOOP
    IF ( CUR_REC.DEPT = L_DEPARTMENT1 OR CUR_REC.DEPT = L_DEPARTMENT2
        OR CUR_REC.DEPT = L_DEPARTMENT3 ) THEN
        O_RETURN_CODE   := 0;
        EXIT my_loop WHEN 1=1; -- or GOTO loop_end;
    ELSE
        O_RETURN_CODE   := 1;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
<<loop_end>>
....
....
```